# JOOQ:Delete List of record in one shot?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How to delete `List` of records from a single query in `JOOQ`? Is this possible with `JOOQ` API? Or i have to delete record one by one ,Just get one record fire query and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that!

#### Using a batch statement

You can batch-delete records through

- [`DSLContext.batchDelete(UpdatableRecord...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete%28org.jooq.UpdatableRecord...%29) or
- [`DSLContext.batchDelete(Collection<? extends UpdatableRecord<?>>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete%28java.util.Collection%29)

Example:

```
MyTableRecord record1 = //...
MyTableRecord record2 = //...
DSL.using(configuration).batchDelete(record1, record2).execute();
```

This will generate a JDBC batch statement, which can be executed much faster than single deletes.

#### Using a single DELETE statement with an IN predicate

Another option would be to create a single `DELETE` statement as such:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(configuration);
// This intermediate result is only used to extract ID values later on
Result<MyTableRecord> result = create.newResult(MY_TABLE);
result.add(record1);
result.add(record2);

create.delete(MY_TABLE)
      .where(MY_TABLE.ID.in(result.getValues(MY_TABLE.ID))
      .execute();
```

Comment: You passes record1,record2 ... Can we pass list of records? I mean Collection ?

Comment: See the updated answer. Feel free to browse the Javadoc. Often, a lot of questions can be answered immediately from the API.